# Matlab: Number of files in a folder excluding the file names information

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a way to count the number of files in a folder path without caring about the names of the files. DIR function extracts all the names which is unnecessary for my specific application.

Since I'm looking at 100 folders and each folder includes almost 35000 files in it, it is very time consuming if I use the "dir" function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What operating system? Also it may be helpful for you to show us the code that works but is slow

Comment: It's on Windows. Consider it as a for loop for all the folders and inside the loop I count the number of files

Comment: What are the actual commands you're using to count the files though.

Comment: Files  =  dir(CurrentPath );  NumOfFiles = length(Files);

Comment: What does "very time consuming" mean?

Comment: @excaza roughly 1 min for each folder. I want it to be done in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @Mike Be careful with that as that's not going to count files properly since it includes the directories `.` and `..`. You should do `nFiles = sum(~[Files.isdir])`

Comment: Thats right. I've added the extension of files in the code: like '*.bmp'

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
someDir = 'c:\Users\You\somePath\' //whatever directory you want to do it for
[status,cmdout] = System(['dir ' someDir  '*.* /s'])
```

and you can parse out the number of files from `cmdout`

This should be faster because its just running a system command so you lose all the overhead of matlab.

Comment: Technically, "system" is much slower when I tried it

Comment: interesting I would not expect that